# How to iterate through list of generic dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a json object which is been converted to list of Dictionary. The json is as follows:

```
{
"DataList":
{"Non Fuel":
{
   "sn":"/DataXmlProduct/Customers/DataXml/Customer/DueDate",
   "ItemCode":"/DataXmlProduct/Customers/DataXml/Customer/InvoiceNo",
   "Qty":"/DataXmlProduct/Customers/DataXml/Customer/CustomerNo",
   "Amount":"DataXml/Customer/TotalCurrentCharges"
  },

  "Fuel":{
   "sn":"/DataXmlProduct/Customers/DataXml/Customer/InvoiceNo",
   "ItemCode":"/DataXmlProduct/Customers/DataXml/Customer/InvoiceNo",
   "Amount":"DataXml/Customer/TotalCurrentCharges"
  }
 }
}
```

The result is (`Dictionary<string, object>`), Here the value of each dictionary is again a dictionary and I need to dynamically iterate through each values of the dictionary and get the last key & value where the value is a Xpath and need to get the values from the xpath.
Kindly help me with a solution to iterate through the dictionary. It should be generic since the json format can vary based on user input.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the actual values (such as the contents of `fuel`) come out as a `KeyValuePair<string, object>`, then you could do this with a recursive method:

```
public static void ParseData(object source)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> Dict;
    KeyValuePair<string, object> Kvp;
    if ((Dict = source as Dictionary<string,object>) != null)
    {
        foreach(var kvp in Dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
            ParseData(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
    elseif ((Kvp = source as KeyValuePair<string, object>) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", Kvp.Key, Kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

This makes an assumption or two, but that will iterate through all the data assuming its made of dictionaries and kvps.

Edit: If you've got an XPath and want to get a node then what you'll need to do is prepare an `XMLDocument` with the data in. You can use the code above to walk through the data to help you build an `XMLDocument` and then query the document with your XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic code for processing all the data:

```
static void IterateDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Processing key: " + pair.Key);
            object value = pair.Value;
            var subDictionary = value as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (subDictionary != null)
            {
                // recursive call to process embedded dictionary
                // warning: stackoverflowexception might occur for insanely embedded data: dictionary in dictionary in dictionary in . etc
                IterateDictionary(subDictionary);
            }
            else
            {
                // process data
                System.Console.WriteLine("data: {0}", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest using Json.NET to serialize your objects, however, you've mentioned that the input is dynamic, but are the attributes standardized? Looking at your sample, there are several repeated fields. You can deserialize the json into your classes by doing

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YOUR_CUSTOM_OBJECT>
```